# Как проинициаллизировать статические обьекты структуры(структура расположена в классе)?

Tags: ооп, c++

Здравствуйте!

Есть такая штука:

```
const int sm=10;
class X{
...
public:
    struct SMOKE{
        int sV;
        static int index_sm;
    };
static SMOKE SM[sm];
};
int X::SMOKE index_sm=0;// на это не ругается
rocket_parent::SMOKE rocket_parent::SM;// ругается на это/ Всяк пробовал...
```

Вот что пишет:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct rocket_parent::SMOKE * X::SM" (?SM@X@@2PAUSMOKE@1@A)
1>C:\...\ : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ideone.com/LHkqpO

Comment: Вы бы добавили важную часть кода к ответу, а? Чтобы было понятно, как надо делать, не заглядывая на ideone.

Comment: А можно X::SM[0].sV = 2; это задать не в функции?

Comment: Попробовал сделать вот так: X::SM[sm]={}; Все компилируется, даже некоторое время работает. а потом вылетает ошибка типа ацесс виолейшен... что за ерунда.

Comment: @Alerr: Уверен, что access violation — это совсем другая проблема.

Comment: Есть предположения почему она стала появляться именно тогда, когда я обращаюсь к статической переменной SM?, причем try/catch ee не берут... Если SMOKE создать как глобальную структуру, то все хорошо.

Comment: Да я понимаю, это было сделано исключительно для обнаружения ошибки... Просто выхода за пределы массива не было, а больше ничего плохого там и не может произойти. Буду разбираться. Спасибо.